# Is it portable to call executable with full path "/bin/..."?

Tags: linux, unix, msys, msys2

For the RTOS I'm writing ( http://www.distortos.org ) I need to run `find` as part of the build configuration process (from `make menuconfig` target). For Windows I assume that user has MSYS2 installed, so `find.exe` is available. The only problem with this particular file is that Windows also has such file in `C:/Windows/system32` (supposedly it is something close to `grep`). So depending on the order of folders in your `PATH` environment variable you get one or the other if trying to call the file by just the name.

I've found that calling this program as `/bin/find` from the `Makefile` or in shell script works both in Windows and on (my) Linux. What is most important - doing it that way always calls `find.exe` from MSYS2, no matter what is the order of folders in `PATH`. So I'm wondering - is it OK to call `find` this way, or maybe it is not portable and I just had luck that it works for me?

Comment: The contents of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` vary, somewhat arbitrarily, from one system to another. Historically `/bin` contained executables that were needed early in the boot process, and `/usr/bin` was often on a separate partition, but that's largely obsolete. Sometimes one is a symlink to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be more portable to refer to it as `/usr/bin/find`.  For example, on Fedora `/bin` is actually a symlink to `/usr/bin`, so either works:

```
bash-4.3$ ls -l /bin/find
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 222608 Dec 28 18:26 /bin/find
bash-4.3$ ls -l /usr/bin/find
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 222608 Dec 28 18:26 /usr/bin/find
```

But on a recent Ubuntu:

```
root@69ca68fbe5c0:/# ls -l /bin/find
ls: cannot access /bin/find: No such file or directory
root@69ca68fbe5c0:/# ls -l /usr/bin/find
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 229992 Jan  6  2014 /usr/bin/find
```

Comment: Yes, it works with `/usr/bin/find` too (I actually checked this variant first), but I don't know which location is better... On my Linux `/bin` is also a symlink to `/usr/bin`, the real folder where `find.exe` is in MSYS2 is also reported as `/usr/bin` (by `which find`) and it really is sth like `C:\msys64\usr\bin`.

Comment: I guess I was suggesting that `/usr/bin/find` is empirically better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not hard-coding the path to `find` and instead instruct Windows  users that they must run your script inside the MSYS2 environment.  MSYS2 will put its own bin directories near the beginning of the path so that `find` always gets the MSYS2 version instead of the Microsoft version.

If you hard-code the path to `find` then you make things be more brittle than they need to be.